# Каким образом приложение андроид может определять метод в классе?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

Есть приложение, у него есть .so библиотеки внутри apk файла, и в коде у него есть статический класс у которого есть метод такого типа:

```
public class JNILibClass {
    public static native Object nativeMethod(int i, Object... o);
}
```

Я уже все что можно перепробовал не могу понять каким образом он появляется, ни что ни где в коде его не генерирует, как тогда он может появляться? Может ли сама библиотека которая на языке C написана, каким-то образом определять этот метод при загрузке или может есть еще пути? Подскажите.

И еще я пробовал хукать саму библиотеку C (libc.so), но когда я вызываю этот метод то он должен был бы обращатся к методу библиотеки, но он этого не делает, тогда каким образом может быть ситуация когда в коде, метод пустой, при вызове его он отрабатывает(тестировал - работает), но при этом он не обращается к ни к одной из библиотек при вызове?

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понял - вы собираете приложение из исходников и в готовом появляется класс? У проекта наверное есть зависимости и это что-то из них. Если метод работает - то он однозначно связан с нативным кодом, бинарник на месте и даже загружен, иначе будет исключение.